# TSQL - list multiple records across multiple columns

Tags: sql-server

is there a way to list multiple records across multiple columns eg. 2 columns? There must be no link between the records that are present in the same row.

current:

| id | date | hours |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/2022 | M |
| 2 | 02/01/2022 | P |
| 3 | 07/01/2022 | P |
| 7 | 01/01/2022 | N |

result:

| id | date | hours | id | date | hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/2022 | M | 2 | 02/01/2022 | P |
| 3 | 07/01/2022 | P | 7 | 01/01/2022 | N |

Thanks for your help

---

i tried with 3 columns:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN rn % 3 = 2 THEN id END) AS id1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn % 3 = 2 THEN date END) AS date1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn % 3 = 2 THEN hours END) AS hours1,

       MAX(CASE WHEN rn % 3 = 1 THEN id END) AS id2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn % 3 = 1 THEN date END) AS date2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn % 3 = 1 THEN hours END) AS hours2

       MAX(CASE WHEN rn % 3 = 0 THEN id END) AS id3,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn % 3 = 0 THEN date END) AS date3,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn % 3 = 0 THEN hours END) AS hours3
FROM cte
GROUP BY (rn - 1) / 3;
```

but the result is not sorted by id.
The result is not the following:

| id1 | date1 | hours1 | id2 | date2 | hours2 | id3 | date3 | hours3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/2022 | M | 2 | 02/01/2022 | P | 3 | 07/01/2022 | P |
| 7 | 01/01/2022 | N |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Comment: How do you decide that 2 goes with 1 and 7 goes with 3?

Comment: according to the order of the id field

Comment: Charlieface I tried with 1 then 2 then 0. But sorting is not done by id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use a pivot query with the help of `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN rn % 2 = 1 THEN id END) AS id1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn % 2 = 1 THEN date END) AS date1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn % 2 = 1 THEN hours END) AS hours1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn % 2 = 0 THEN id END) AS id2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn % 2 = 0 THEN date END) AS date2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn % 2 = 0 THEN hours END) AS hours2
FROM cte
GROUP BY (rn - 1) / 2;
```

Comment: tim thanks for the help. can you give me an example with 3 columns? Thank you

Comment: Just replace the mod and divisor 2 with 3, and also add more terms to the select statement for the third column.